# How to make sure that kendo grid detailInit can be called everytime

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that uses a detailInit, it only gets called once when you select a row, and if you reselect that row then it doesn't fire again. My issue is that I need to fire the detailInit everytime because I have a grid inside there that needs to call the server everytime it gets viewed so the data is current.

One way that I thought of is just using a global variable as an object and pass in the masterrow's id when the detailInit is fired, and then check the global variable on the change event to see if that row has already been opened, and if it has then make a call to the server. But I am not to sure if that would be the best way to do it...

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [detailExpand](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/detailexpand) you can change detailRow datasource (on reopen):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    {
      name: "Beverages"
    },
    {
      name: "Food",
      products: [
        { name: "Ham" },
        { name: "Bread" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  detailTemplate: 'Products: <div class="grid"></div>',
  detailExpand: function(e) {
    console.log("expand: ", e);

    var selectedColumnName = e.sender.dataItem(e.masterRow).name;
    console.log(selectedColumnName);

    e.detailRow.find(".grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: [
        { name: "Tea" },
        { name: "Coffee" }
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

Example: [Detail row dataSource](https://dojo.telerik.com/UVAHEcIS/2)

Comment: This looks good, but I am calling a function in the detailInit.. IE detailInit: myfunction

Comment: then you can call `detailExpand: myFunction`. myFunction receives `e` as parameter: https://dojo.telerik.com/OfUNeweJ

Comment: So I should remove the detailInit: myfunction and just use the detailExpand: myfunction?

Comment: SO far so good, the only issue I am having is that when I was using detailInit that there was e.data.MyID, but not with this way, how do I get the e.data.MyID?

Comment: e.sender.dataItem(e.masterRow).MyID

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks so much. I learned something new now, that I don't need to use detailInit all the time...